# ¿como puedo centrar un Header fijo con css?

Tags: html, css, div

¡Buenas! tengo un problema que me pasa contínuamente y necesito ayuda... Cada vez que voy a dejar un header fijo (con float:fixed) la caja contenedora se mueve y "sale" ligeramente hacia la derecha... he intentado todo pero sigo sin poder resolverlo. En el box model me aparece que el float "right" está en -8, y cuando quito el fixed, simplemente desaparece.
os dejo el código de html y css:

HTML

```
<body>
    <header class="Header-principal">
        <div class="Encabezado">
            <nav class="logo float-left">
                <a href=""><img src="images\logo.png"></a>
            </nav>
        <!--revisar logo-->
            <div class="titulo float-left">
                <h2>Miguel Ángel Palacios Peláez</h2>
            </div>
            <nav class="menu-header float-right"><!--Este será el menú de navegación-->
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">¿quién soy?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CV*</a></li><!--INSERTAR:FORMACIÓN+EXPERIENCIA-->
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
.Header-principal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 102px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px; 
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Angel, puedes pasar siempre a ver el tour de la plataforma y ganar tu primer medalla en el proceso [Tour StackOverflow es](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), cuando te refieres a que haz intentado "todo" puedes editar tu pregunta e indicar lo que haz intentado y los errores mostrados.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar las propiedades de especificación de posición, es este caso `left`. Como se trata de un header también deberías utilizar la propiedad `top`.

Por lo tanto tu clase quedaría tal que así:

```
.Header-principal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 102px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```